# Erlang No home for cookie file

Tags: python, erlang, disco

What does "No home for cookie file" mean? And how do I resolve this issue:

```
export BINDIR=/usr/lib/disco/master/ebin/;/usr/lib/erlang/erts-5.10.4/bin/beam -K true -P 10000000 -scl false -stbt s -- -root /usr/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /usr/var/disco info -- -lager handlers [{lager_file_backend,[{file,"/usr/var/disco/log/error.log"}, {level, error}, {size, 1048576000}, {date, "$D0"}, {count, 5}]},{lager_file_backend,[{file,"/usr/var/disco/log/console.log"}, {level, debug}, {size, 1048576000}, {date, "$D0"}, {count, 5}]}] -lager error_logger_hwm 200 -lager crash_log "/usr/var/disco/log/crash.log" -rsh ssh -connect_all false -sname disco_8989_master -pa /usr/lib/disco/master/ebin -pa /usr/lib/disco/master/deps/mochiweb/ebin -pa /usr/lib/disco/master/deps/goldrush/ebin -pa /usr/lib/disco/master/deps/lager/ebin -pa /usr/lib/disco/master/deps/meck/ebin -pa /usr/lib/disco/master/deps/bear/ebin -pa /usr/lib/disco/master/deps/folsom/ebin -pa /usr/lib/disco/master/deps/folsomite/ebin -pa /usr/lib/disco/master/deps/plists/ebin -eval "application:start(disco)"

{error_logger,{{2016,11,7},{17,25,49}},"No home for cookie file",[]}
{error_logger,{{2016,11,7},{17,25,49}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{auth,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.20.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{"No home for cookie file",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,285}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,139}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]},[{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,328}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.10.0>]},{messages,[]},{links,[<0.18.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,610},{stack_size,27},{reductions,139}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2016,11,7},{17,25,49}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,net_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{"No home for cookie file",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,285}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,139}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,auth},{mfargs,{auth,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2016,11,7},{17,25,49}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"No home for cookie file",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,285}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,139}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}}}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_sup},{mfargs,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2016,11,7},{17,25,49}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4']}},{pid,<0.9.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"No home for cookie file",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,285}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,139}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}},[{application_master,init,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,133}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},{ancestors,[<0.8.0>]},{messages,[{'EXIT',<0.10.0>,normal}]},{links,[<0.8.0>,<0.7.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,987},{stack_size,27},{reductions,179}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2016,11,7},{17,25,49}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"No home for cookie file",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,285}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,139}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{\"No home for cookie file\",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,\"auth.erl\"},{line,285}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,\"auth.erl\"},{line,139}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,239}]}]}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
```

More context:

```
 disco@download1-6401:~$ cat $HOME/.erlang.cookie;echo;ls -ail .erlang.cookie 
QCQSMBOQOJCGVKZCUXQL
263466 -rw------- 1 disco disco 20 Nov  4 00:00 .erlang.cookie
```

Comment: I don't see Python in question. Why did you use tag "python" ?

Comment: Normally `BINDIR` and other environment variables and command-line options such as `-home` are set properly by starting Erlang using the `erl` script, normally found in `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin`. Are you really attempting to start Erlang the way you're showing? Also, `BINDIR` is normally not set to an `ebin` directory as you show, but is instead set by the `erl` script to something like `$ROOTDIR/erts-8.1/bin` where `ROOTDIR` is something like `/usr/local/lib/erlang` or `/usr/lib/erlang`.

Comment: @furas disco is a python based map reduce which uses erlang on the backend.

Comment: @SteveVinoski thank you for the reply. I was attempting to start erlang as shown. I looked at the /usr/bin/erlang script and see what you mean. i am indifferent on the how, i mostly just wanted to debug/execute `application:start(disco)` and couldn't get beyond the erlang cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `disco` using the script it provides for starting it, stopping it, checking its status, etc. The steps below worked for me, but note that they require `git`, `make`, [`rebar`](https://github.com/rebar/rebar), and a [working Erlang installation](https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang/). (I use ellipses below to indicate lengthy output not import enough to show here.)

```
$ git clone git@github.com:discoproject/disco.git
...
$ cd disco
$ make
...
$ PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH ./bin/disco start
Master bignosk:8989 started
```

I initially tried this with the latest version of Erlang, 19.x, but the build failed, so I backed down to Erlang 18.3 and then everything worked fine.

Comment: Is `.erlang.cookie` related  to `magic cookie` http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html#id88336

Comment: @jmunsch: yes, what's in your `~/.erlang.cookie` file is used as a "magic cookie" when appropriate.